# Phonegap file transfer : how to prevent multipart data?

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to upload a file (image) to Amazon S3 using cordova file transfer plugin. According to the docs: "if a header named Content-Type is present, multipart form data will NOT be used". Nevertheless multipart form data IS USED, even if this header is included. Here is my code:

```
            ft.upload(
                path,
                url,
                function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                },
                {
                    httpMethod  : 'PUT',
                    fileName    :  name,
                    mimeType    :  type,
                    chunkedMode :  false,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type'   :  type,
                        //'Content-Length' :  size,
                        'x-amz-acl'      : 'public-read',
                        'Expect'         : '100-continue'
                        //'Content-Disposition': 'render',
                        //'Connection'     : 'close'
                    }
                }
            );
```

After uploading the binary is wrapped:

--+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="photo_032.jpg" Content-Type: image/jpeg Content-Length: 43084

{binary data}

--+++++org.apache.cordova.formBoundary--

How can I prevent Phonegap from using mulptipart form data? I've already tried different versions of the plugin, but still get the same result.

Comment: If the docs says some thing and it doesn't work as the docs say, then file an issue http://issues.cordova.io/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue has been fixed. A guy from PG community helped me:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap-file-transfer-how-to-prevent-multipart-data?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=16076747#reply_16076747

I used PG build and the plugin there was outdated. Once I installed the last version of cordova-plugin-media-transfer from npm and built locally the app started to upload to Amazon with no issues and no multipart data were used.